# checking the transmission fluid

Tags: automatic-transmission, dodge, ram, van, atf

I put transmission fluid in my 2002 dodge 2500 van transmission. It keeps reading the same, but when I look at the back side of the stick after adding fluid, it looks like it is going up. Really odd.

Comment: Can you take a picture of both sides of your dipstick while you are reading the fluid level?

Comment: You are checking with the engine running, at operating temperature and on a level surface, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Are you pouring the ATF down the dipstick tube?

The dipstick tube has a bend in it.  When you pour fluid down the tube, the fluid follows gravity and tends to run down one side of the tube and bend.  The fluid doesn't all go into the transmission; a small amount clings to the sides of the tube.

When you put the dipstick in, the "back side" is being wiped against the side of the tube that has the fresh fluid sticking on it.  The "front side" does not wipe against anything.

You should follow the "front side" reading.